# How to create an object that creates a reference to a List?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a list of type food. I have created the object food. This list is an arraylist. I am trying to create an object that creates a reference to this List. Not sure what the best way to do this is.

Comment: Please see the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page. The question isn't clear; if you have a reference to the list already, and you want to create an object that references this list, either pass the reference to the object's constructor, or set it using a setter method. What's the specific issue you're having?

Comment: I have a List already created that adds the foods as they come in, but how do i create an object that references this list that I can use later without cloning/copying it?

Comment: `SomeObject foo = new SomeObject(theListReference);` and its ctor takes a `List`? I'm still unclear what the conceptual hurdle is.

Comment: So in the new object class create a constructor that has the arraylist as a parameter?

Comment: That is one option, as stated in the original comment. There are others. What makes the most "sense" depends on what you're actually doing. But your issue still eludes me--I don't understand what the problem is.

Comment: Im trying to use the same memory space and not simply trying to copy the entire array since it would take memory space

Comment: That's not my question--passing references to objects doesn't copy them (which can lead to a variety of entertaining bugs). I'm trying to understand why this question is being asked, since this is pretty much just how Java works.

Comment: I am learning .